# Reinstall corrupted vmlinuz-linux

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, uefi

I'm dual booting Arch Linux and Windows 8.1. I forgot to disable "Fast Startup" on Windows, and it corrupted `vmlinuz-linux` in the `/boot` partition. When I try to boot into Arch from [Gummiboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot), I receive the following message:

```
Error loading \vmlinuz-linux: Volume Corrupt
```

I've setup network access and a chroot with all partitions available. But how do I actually reinstall `vmlinuz-linux`?

Comment: @jasonwryan I tried that exact command, but that complained about `vmlinuz-linux` being invalid.

Comment: Run `pacman -Syyu linux`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this question was answered in a comment, I wanted to clarify what is going on so you can understand this issue in the future.

vmlinuz is the name of the Linux kernel executable. If this file is corrupted, there is no way you will be able to boot the Linux kernel, making an operating system impossible to use. (Programs are useless without a kernel, and vice versa).

The reason `pacman -Syyu linux` resolved this issue for you is because the arch package manager reloaded their Linux executable file onto your system. If no package manager was available, you would then need to recompile the Linux kernel and manually add `vmlinuz` to your `/boot` directory.